# Safely remove an LVM PV

Tags: lvm

How can I safely remove an LVM physical volume (PV) without data loss?  There is enough space on the remaining PV to hold the data.

Comment: answer would be to do those 3 steps: [4.6. Online Data Relocation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/logical_volume_manager_administration/index#online_relocation), [4.3.7. Removing Physical Volumes from a Volume Group](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/logical_volume_manager_administration/index#VG_remove_PV), optional: [4.2.5. Removing Physical Volumes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/logical_volume_manager_administration/index#PV_remove)

Comment: ok in the "duplicate" the (non-accepted) answer with the screenshots does use `pvmove`